# How to read a line from text file, call function on that line and move to second line and so on?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

Forgive me if the question is stupid, but I cannot move the reader to a second line. Calling function on every input line is important.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {

    ///////////

}
```

Comment: You need to store the value returned by `reader.readLine` in some other variable and use it as you need.

Comment: This helps ? I want to parse every line, make the String go through a function, split strings, I will display the output and so on till the file ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    String line;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        myFunc (line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader!=null)
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

You can also use a `Scanner` instead:

```
File file = new File ("input.txt");
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        myFunc (scanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (scanner!=null)
        scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the value returned by `reader.readLine` into an additional variable (just like I said in my comment). Modify your code to look like the following:

```
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //use "line" as per your needs
}
```